# Google People API: no way to search contacts?

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-people-api

Just noticed today the following announcement:

> Google Contacts API is now deprecated and is scheduled for sunset on June 15, 2021. Apps should instead use the People API.

Which is fine except the fact that People API does not provide any way to search contacts like the old Contacts API provided with ?q=.

> Fulltext query on contacts data fields. The API currently supports simple search queries such as q=term1 term2 term3 and exact search queries such as q="term1 term2 term3"

Is there any way to do this simple text searching using People API?

Answer (score 2):

So far it is not possible, but there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/73864682) for it open on Google's Public Issue Tracker.

Give it a "star" to indicate that you are also interested in the feature - this will help to increase visibility.